# "Server Error" displayed on the browser when using the PHP function of imap_header

Tags: php, email, imap

**Summary**

I try to read the information of the first letter in my mailbox. Suppose that "mail.example.com" is my mail server site, "userid" is my e-mail address and "userpwd" is my password. Below is the PHP code.

```
<?php
$num=1;         //To read the first letter

$MAILSERVER="{mail.example.com:143/notls}INBOX";
$link=imap_open($MAILSERVER,"userid","userpwd");
$header=imap_header($link,$num);

echo "From: $header[fromaddress]<br>";
echo "To: $header[toaddress]<br>";
echo "Date: $header[Date]<br>";
echo "Subject: $header[Subject]<br><br>";
echo imap_body($link,$num);

imap_close($link);
?>
```

**Questions**

I have two questions:

1. According to the PHP code above, why the output result is "Server Error"?
2. Why `$link` has no return value when we do not add "/notls" on line 4?

Comment: Is there no more detail in the error? Just "server error" and that's it? What does your mailserver log show at the time of your connection attempt?

Comment: what is the mail service you are using? notls is the mailbox path that is used by the mailbox service provider. It differs for each provider

Comment: @Oldskool Below is the error log:
[16-Dec-2015 17:15:33 Asia/Taipei] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in /home/example/public_html/test/view.php on line 8
[16-Dec-2015 17:15:33 Asia/Taipei] PHP Notice:  Unknown: SECURITY PROBLEM: insecure server advertised AUTH=PLAIN (errflg=1) in Unknown on line 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this. you are using invalid array index

```
$MAILSERVER="{mail.example.com:143/notls}INBOX";
$link=imap_open($MAILSERVER,"userid","userpwd");
$header=imap_header($link,$num);

echo "From:". $header['fromaddress']."<br>";
echo "To:". $header['toaddress']."<br>";
echo "Date:".$header['Date']."<br>";
echo "Subject:". $header['Subject']."<br><br>";
echo imap_body($link,$num);

imap_close($link);
?>
```